# Use Automator to run Python script when files added to folder

Tags: terminal, automator, python

I have a folder, `Books`, where I add all of the .pdf files that need to be uploaded to a Kindle. I have a Python script that does that, but instead of manually running it, I want to check whenever files are added to `Books`, run that Python script. Is there any way to do this using Automator, or even without Automator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch Automator, and choose 'Folder Action' as the document type. 
Then set the target folder in the drop-down menu at the top of the window.

Add a "Run Shell Script" action. You have to choose one of the 'shell' environments in the drop-down menu, which include either the system python `/usr/bin/python` (which is v2, and EOLed); or a Unix shell, where you can call the python script externally, with something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 <path to python script> "$1"
```

Alternatively to using the Run Shell Script action, you could use the AppleScript action with a `do shell script` command.

Save your workflow. The workflow is saved to `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts`

You can configure Folder Actions for any folder by right-clicking in the Finder and selecting "Folder Actions Setup".

*(I have had intermittent success hacking the saved workflow in a text editor, and altering the 'shell' path to another environment. `/usr/bin/swift` works, but `/usr/local/bin/python` doesn't. More work required.)*

Comment: I have done everything you said, and I am running it from the zsh shell. When running the Python script from the Automator though, (pressing the run button at the top-right), a subprocess in the Python script fails to work. It says 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ebook-convert': 'ebook-convert'`
ebook-convert is the command I am running in the subprocess. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Are you quoting the full path for this subprocess? From my testing, I wouldn't rely on any assumptions about relative paths.

Comment: I am quoting relative paths, but in my shell Automator script, I change directory to the required directory, I also just tried it with full paths and it didn't work.

Comment: Also, I changed all of the relative paths of absolute paths, and it continued to work when I executed it in the Terminal `python3 kindle.py` but now, in Automator, it gives error 127 when running the subprocess.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help! So I understood what was happening. For some reason, ebook-convert wouldn't work for the shell script, so I had to use the full path to the command, which was `/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert`, then the arguments, which worked!